# How to run a strapi in another developer system, if i run the strapi, from cloned project in git

Tags: next.js, strapi

⠼ Loading Strapi[ERROR]  There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│                                                                      ││   Error: Missing apiToken.salt. Please set apiToken.salt in          ││   config/admin.js (ex: you can generate one using Node with          ││   crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')).                      ││   For security reasons, prefer storing the secret in an              ││   environment variable and read it in config/admin.js. See           ││   https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-gu   ││   ides/configurations/optional/environment.html#configuration-usin   ││   g-environment-variables.                                           ││   at Object.checkSaltIsDefined                                       ││   (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strapi\node_modules@st   ││   rapi\admin\server\services\api-token.js:285:13)                    ││   at module.exports (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strap   ││   i\node_modules@strapi\admin\server\bootstrap.js:98:19)            ││   at async Strapi.runLifecyclesFunctions                             ││   (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strapi\node_modules@st   ││   rapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:436:7)                                  ││   at async Strapi.bootstrap (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\websi   ││   te-strapi\node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:413:5)        ││   at async Strapi.load (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-st   ││   rapi\node_modules@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:419:5)             ││   at async Object.develop                                            ││   (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strapi\node_modules@st   ││   rapi\admin\dist_chunks\index-1a74fa41.js:1241:28)                 ││   at async develop                                                   ││   (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strapi\node_modules@st   ││   rapi\admin\dist_chunks\develop-4d25a6e0.js:52:5)                  ││   at async Command.parseAsync (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\web   ││   site-strapi\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:923:5)           ││   at async Module.runStrapiCommand                                   ││   (D:\Medtekviyab\Alliance-Website\website-strapi\node_modules@st   ││   rapi\strapi\dist\commands\index.js:124:3)

need to fix this and run properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I created two folders for my project, one for the frontend and one for the CMS folder then used the 4.12.5 version of the Strapi, not the latest version, and it worked